# Search for matching subject ids files on Sharepoint using R

Tags: r, sharepoint, shiny, r-markdown, tidyverse

Wondering if it is possible to use R and a list of subject id's to check if each id has a matching file under a SharePoint certain folder? And if a file doesn't exist, it should return list of subject id's.

For example:

In R I have a list of ids

| subject_ids |
| --- |
| 191-94120 |
| 191-36039 |
| 191-43890 |
| 191-54230 |
| 191-34000 |

Sharepoint files

(sharepoint.com)

| subject_ids |
| --- |
| 2_191-94120_20220808 |
| 2_191-36039_20220808 |
| 2_191-43890_20220908 |
| 2_191-54230_20220908 |
| 2_191-90000_20220908 |

Then the output will return 191-34000 since there are no files for this participant. And secondarily, for it to return 2_191-90000_20220908 because there is no subject_id that matches this file.